# Many to many relationship retrieve a column connected to pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a many to many relationships (pivot). There are 3 tables, namely banks, principles, and bank_principles. Under Principles, I want to get the principle column to show under the Banks table. The bank_principle table consists of bank_id and principle_id. I want to retrieve principle column under the Principle table and have it shown under the Banks data when I run it in the console. How can it be done?

My controller:

```
$bankTransfer = Banks::with('principles')->get();
```

My pivot relationship under banks:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Principle', 'bank_principle', 'bank_id', 'principle_id')->using('App\Models\BankPrinciple');
```

My pivot relationship under principle:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Banks', 'bank_principle');
```

Comment: loop through the `$bankTransfer->principles` to get individual principal data of corresponding bank data

Comment: @Sohel0415 - thanks for your response. I'm not sure how to go about this. Can you maybe give an example? Just to mention - the banks data shows in an array of objects and then the principle data in an array, with the principle column under in the array.

Comment: please show what `dd($bankTransfer)` gives??

Comment: `(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Ta]
0
:
account_number
:
2147483647
bank_detail_id
:
5
bank_number_name
:
"Default"
branch_code
:
145209
created_at
:
"2018-03-12 15:43:27"
deleted_at
:
null
id
:
1
is_approved
:
0
name_of_account
:
"J Smith"
name_of_branch
:
"Lifestyle"
swift_code
:
"fdfsdfdsf"
uniqueKey
:
"504e92d9-edbc-4aab-a358-43744a68b58d"
updated_at
:
"2018-03-12 15:43:27"
user_id
:
6
principles
:
Array(1)
0
:
id
:
(...)
pivot
:
(...)
principle
:
"rr44"
show_app`

Comment: not like this, please make a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `$bankTransfer` to access individual `$bankTransfer` object and then loop through `$bankTransfer->priciples` to access individual `principle`.

```
foreach($bankTransfer as $bankTransferEach){
    //here you can access bank transfer data like $bankTransferEach->account_number
      foreach($bankTransferEach->principles as $principle){
          //here you can access principle table data like $principle->column_name
      }

}
```